# How to recover deleted frame in Figma?

Tags: delete-file, recover, figma

I need help. Two days ago I was making a portfolio website in Figma and somehow I've deleted the whole frame of my design. I know that Figma has that autosave and I am so angry right now. I don't know how to recover or undo that action. Please help!!!
Thank you upfront...

Comment: Not enough info to answer, imho

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 8):

Figma has a feature hidden away called **Version History**. As long as you've kept the file in your Figma account, you should be able to restore the file back to a version that had your frame.

**How To Use Version History**

I've attached a screenshot below.

- Open up your file, press the dropdown beside your file name
  and then press "Show Version History" from the menu.
- A sidebar will then appear on the right and you can click through
  Figma's autosaves to find a version with your frame in.
- I tend to then press the dots beside the version I want to restore and
  hit "Duplicate". This way you can maintain both your current file plus
  the version you wish to restore (as it gets created as a new, seperate file).

**Please Note**

- Figma only makes available **30 days** of version history on the free
  tier. If your edits fall outside of this history period, you can try
  upgrading your account for a month to extend the version history
  available to you.
- Also I've noticed that Figma tends to only make new versions of files
  a couple of times a day (depending on how much editing of the file
  you do). So, you may not find the exact point you're after, but you
  should be able to restore some of it!
- Thought it was also worth mentioning, at anytime you can hit the "+" in the top right of the Version History panel to create a checkpoint. While I tend to use pages for version control, I sometimes do this before I have to make a global change to my file after some client feedback (like adjusting text/color styles).

Hope this helps David! (And I hope this gets to you before your 30 days of history is up!)

[image: Figma File Menu]

Answer (score 1):

We just found if you go into "Drafts" there's a tab at the top for "Deleted".  Check in there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this only works if the file is created by 'you'. Not sure if it will work on a file that was originally created by someone else.

Comment: This could have been just a comment for a previous answer